# Update and Delete does not work in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on web api project and I want implement grid with CRUD operations.
These are my web api methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllPosting() {}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPostingById(int Id) {}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] vGeneralLedger item) {}

[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, vGeneralLedger item) {}

[HttpDelete]
public void Delete(int id) {}
```

In my view page, I am defined jQgrid:

```
jQuery("#generalLedgerGrid").jqGrid({
...
...
});

function updateDialog(action) {
    return {
        url: API_URL, // 'http://localhost:xxxxx/api/GeneralLedgerDetails/'
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterShowForm: function (formId) { },
        jqmodal: true,
        afterSubmit: function (params) {
            var list = $("#generalLedgerGrid");
            var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
            rowData = list.getRowData(selectedRow);
            params.url += rowData.Id;
            params.mtype = action;
        },
        bSubmit: "Submit",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        width: "400",
        reloadAfterSubmit: true
    };
}

jQuery("#generalLedgerGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#generalLedgersPager',
    { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
    updateDialog('PUT'),
    updateDialog('POST'),
    updateDialog('DELETE')
);
```

When I run application, grid is displayed with all data in the page (view). But, If I want edit row grid, or delete, then always be redirected (when I put breakpoints to my API methods) to

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] vGeneralLedger item)
```

and Edit and Delete functionality not working properly. And there is one more problem: When I want add new records in grid (in opened dialog) and press Save button, my dialog is still open, and when i close the dialog, i must reload page that latest record to be displayed.

And, I have used this tutorial:
http://techbrij.com/add-edit-delete-jqgrid-asp-net-web-api

**UPDATE:**
This is my currently data rows in grid (I just post picture):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvz0c.jpg)

**UPDATE:**
This is GetAllPosting method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllPosting()
    {
        try
        {
            var generalLedgers = _db.genLedgers.Where(x => x.Status == true).Select(a => new
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                finNaturalBusinessYearId = a.finNaturalBusinessYearId,
                finDocumentTypeId = a.finDocumentTypeId,
                AccountNo = a.AccountNo,
                PostingDate = a.PostingDate,
                MaturityDate = a.MaturityDate,
                AmountDebit = a.AmountDebit,
                AmountCredit = a.AmountCredit,
                Balance = a.Balance,
                Description = a.Description,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = 1
            });

            var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            var json = formatter.SerializerSettings;
            json.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            json.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, generalLedgers, formatter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Linq statement in select body correspond with my entity model class properties.

And this is definition for my grid:

**UPDATE:**

```
jQuery("#generalLedgerGrid").jqGrid({
        height: 290,
        width: 1200,
        url: API_URL,
        mtype: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
            Id: "0",
            cell: "",
            repeatitems: false,
            celledit: false
        },
        colNames: ['Id', 'NB Year Id', 'Document Type Id', 'Account No', 'Posting Date', 'Maturity Date', 'Description', 'Total Debit', 'Total Credit', 'Balance'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', align: "center", editable: false, width: "45px" },
        { name: 'finNaturalBusinessYearId', align: "center", editable: true, width: "75px" },
        { name: 'finDocumentTypeId', align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: 'AccountNo', align: "center", editable: true },
        {
            name: 'PostingDate', align: "center", editable: true
        },
        { name: 'MaturityDate', align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: 'Description', align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: 'AmountDebit', align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: 'AmountCredit', align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: 'Balance', align: "center", editable: true }
        ],
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignorecase: true,
        reloadGridOptions: {fromServer: true},
        sortname: "InstallmentDate",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 15, 20],
        pager: '#generalLedgersPager',
        caption: "General Ledger Posting List"
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
This is my Delete method from web api controller:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        finGeneralLedger item = _db.genLedgers.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        item.Status = false;
        item.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        item.UserId = 1;

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: you use `params.url += rowData.Id;` and `params.mtype = action;` in the code of `updateDialog(action)`. Would be not easier to use just `mtype: action` inside of returned object and to use `params.url = API_URL + rowData.Id;` (or `API_URL + "/"`)? In any way I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to catch HTTP traffic between the client and the server. You should verify whether the data posted by jqGrid are correct. Moreover you should always write **which version of jqGrid you use and which fork (free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS, ...)**.

Comment: I am use: trirand.jqGrid.4.6.0 version (free) jqGrid.
I am write mtype: action inside of returned object and params.url = API_URL + rowData.Id, but have no lucky, still not working.

Comment: Did you made the traces of HTTP traffic? It's not only good for the troubleshooting, but it's very good for understanding what you program really do. You can see additional error messages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error in your code consist from the usage `afterSubmit`. The callback will be used **after** the response will be get from the server. I suppose that you just wanted to use another callback `onclickSubmit`, but you used the wrong one.

The correct `onclickSubmit` callback for Add/Edit could be the following

```
onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata, formOper) {
    options.url = API_URL + "/" + encodeURIComponent(postdata[this.id + "_id"]);
    options.mtype = formOper === "add" ? "POST" : "PUT";
}
```

The options of Delete dialog:

```
{
    mtype: "DELETE",
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return ""; // the body MUST be empty in DELETE HTTP requests
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
        options.url = API_URL + "/" + encodeURIComponent(postdata);
    }
}
```

If the value of `API_URL` already contains `/` at the end of the string, then you should replace `API_URL + "/"` `to API_URL` in the code fragments above.