# datepicker not working in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I am working on jqgrid application. In my previous post ([Update and Delete does not work in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958108/update-and-delete-does-not-work-in-jqgrid)) I am posted information about my grid. Now, I have a problem about datepicker on add/edit dialog. 
I have same problem as the one person posted earlier post [DateTimePicker not working inside jqGrid. But it's working outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088792/datetimepicker-not-working-inside-jqgrid-but-its-working-outside-of-it). I was installed plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/. In definition of my grid I wrote:

```
{
    name: 'PostingDate', index: 'PostingDate', align: "center", editable: true, edittype: "text", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" },
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    $(el).datetimepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

Also, I am added onInitializeForm in:

```
jQuery("#generalLedgerGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#generalLedgersPager',
          { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
          {
              closeAfterEdit: true,
              onInitializeForm: function (formid) {
                  $("#PostingDate", formid).datetimepicker();
              }
          },
          {
              closeAfterAdd: true,
              onInitializeForm: function (formid) {
                  $("#PostingDate", formid).datetimepicker();
              }
          },
          ...
}
```

When I implement this, i am not getting an error. The page loads up, but when I try to click Add or Edit, the popup window refuses to show up. How can solve that problem? Appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: You should always write which version of jqGrid you use and which fork (free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS, ...). Moreover you should write an example of input data (srcformat) for the column which you use and which format of the date you expect to display (`01-Dec-2015` for example). You wrote: "i am not getting an error." Which error? Do you want to display the date or datetime? Why you use `datetimepicker` instead of `datepicker` if you have only the date in the input data?

Comment: @Oleg: I just see your message. I am using fork free,version 4.10. (I am download your free jq-grid from GitHub). I want display datetime (like a jqgrid on that site http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateTimepicker.htm). At the begining, i was been used jquery datepicker. But it's not worked and i try to use datetimepicker, and also not working. It does not matter if it is easier to use jquery datepicker, I'll use it. **SrcFormat:** `dd-M-yy` (I think), and format to display `d-M-Y H:i`.. Thanks

Comment: You should provide the demo which have the described problems. You can create it in jsfiddle for example. The parameters of `formatter: "date"` should corresponds to the format of the input data. You use `formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }` without `srcformat`. It means the you have to have ISO format `2015-12-31`. In any way `newformat: "d-M-Y"` means that only the date without the time will be displayed. I recommend you to make `datepicker` first working and then will use `datetimepicker`.